# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged do not work after search with search view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a search view that filter recycler view items; it properly filter items but when I close search view my adapter `notifyDataSetChanged` wont work for example if I add new item to recycler view until I close the app and open it again. This is my code for filtering items.

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
        adapter.resetList(userData.GetAllWords(user.getId()));
    } else {
        final ArrayList<Word> filteredModelList = filter(wordlist, newText);
        adapter.setfilter(filteredModelList);
    }
    return false;
}

private ArrayList<Word> filter(ArrayList<Word> wordlistt, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    final ArrayList<Word> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Word myword : wordlistt) {
        if (myword.getWord().contains(query) || myword.getTranslation().contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(myword);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

And this is my code in adapter

```
public void setfilter(ArrayList<Word> filteredwordlist) {
    wordlist = new ArrayList<>();
    wordlist.addAll(filteredwordlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void resetList(ArrayList<Word> newWordlist){
    wordlist=new ArrayList<>();
    wordlist.addAll(newWordlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I even reset my adapter when search view is closed like this

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
    adapter=new WordAdapter(MainActivity.this,userData.GetAllWords(user.getId()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

but still nothing change in my recycler view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating object of array everytime which means Adapter does not have same data instance to notify do this, just create wordlist object once in constructor rest clear it and add item in it.

```
 public void setfilter(ArrayList<Word> filteredwordlist) {
    //wordlist = new ArrayList<>();
    wordlist.clear();
    wordlist.addAll(filteredwordlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Do same when reseting,

Comment: tenx man  for the answer i tried it now recyclerview is changin but if i add new item all the previous items will add !!!

Comment: oh tanx brother i removed searchView.setOnCloseListener and now its working .. i love you :d and sry if my reputution is under 15

Answer (score 2):

If you do this `adapter=new WordAdapter(...);`, then the RecyclerView lose the reference on your adapter. And you won't modify the RecyclerView's adapter anymore.

The same applies for your `getFilter`and `setFilter()`. The adapter lose the reference on your wordlist with `wordList = new WordList()`.

Try using:

```
wordList.clear();
```

And not recreating your adapter. But only change the list content.

Comment: tanx dear clear is working now sry if my reputation is under 15 you deserve +1